# PyMongo Aggregation "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'"

Tags: pymongo, aggregation

I'm sure there is an error in my code since I'm a newby to pyMongo, but I'll give it a go.  The data in MongoDB is 167k+ and is as follows:

```
{'overall': 5.0,
 'reviewText': {'ago': 1,
                'buy': 2,
                'daughter': 1,
                'holiday': 1,
                'love': 2,
                'niece': 1,
                'one': 2,
                'still': 1,
                'today': 1,
                'use': 1,
                'year': 1},
 'reviewerName': 'dcrm'}
```

I would like to get a tally of terms used within that `reviewText` field for all 5.0 ratings.  I have run the following code and I get the error that follows.  Any insight?

```rb
#1 Find the top 20 most common words found in 1-star reviews.

aggr = [{"$unwind": "$reviewText"}, 
        {"$group": { "_id": "$reviewText", "word_freq": {"$sum":1}}}, 
        {"$sort": {"word_freq": -1}},
        {"$limit": 20},
        {"$project": {"overall":"$overall", "word_freq":1}}]
disk_use = { 'allowDiskUse': True }
findings = list(collection.aggregate(aggr, disk_use))

for item in findings:
    p(item)
```

As you can see, I came across the 'allDiskUse' component since I seemed to exceed the 100MB threshold.  But the error that I get is:

```rb
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'
```

Comment: If you haven't resolved the issue, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787253/975178) to a similar issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are quite close, `allowDiskUse` is named parameter not a dictionary so the statement should be like this

```
findings = list(collection.aggregate(aggr, allowDiskUse=True))
```

or

```
findings = list(collection.aggregate(aggr, **disk_use ))
```

Answer (score 0):

ManishSingh response is the best, but if you don't get exactly what he means and why you are having this error I can clarify what you have and why this is not correct:

The problem might be that you are using "allowDiskUse" with quotes like this:

```
findings = list(collection.aggregate(aggr, {"allowDiskUse": True}))  # wrong
```

but the correct is this:

```
findings = list(collection.aggregate(aggr, allowDiskUse=True)) # correct
```