# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference' in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

hi I have an error with this code
the error is

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'
```

what I'm trying to do is to print some fields but when I print it shows an error, and after searching the internet they say to write allowDiskUse:True but the same error appear also to write sort but again the same

```
    group ={ "$group":{
     "_id": "$book.id",
     "title":{"$first":"$book.title"} ,
     "place":{"$first":"$book.place"},
     'authors_id':{"$first":'$authors_id'}}

}   
    project ={ "$project":{
     "_id": False,
     "book.id": True,
     "book.title":True ,
     "book.place":True,
     'authors_id':True}
        
    
}  
    
    sort={"$sort":{
    "_id":-1}}
cursor=books.aggregate([sort,project,group],{"allowDiskUse" : True})
for x in cursor:

    pprint(x)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyMongo Aggregation "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '\_txn\_read\_preference'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011870/pymongo-aggregation-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-txn-read-p)

Comment: No actually it did not work

Comment: Did you get a different error?

Comment: no it is the same error